# What happens when a PHP object is echoed?

Tags: php, oop

If you look at the usage for this library,
https://github.com/Gregwar/Formidable

You have,

```
$form = new Gregwar\Formidable\Form('forms/example.html');

$form->handle(function() {
    echo "Form OK!";
}, function($errors) {
    echo "Errors: <br/>";
    foreach ($errors as $error) {
        echo "$error<br />";
    }
});

echo $form;
```

My question is, how is this done?
How do you echo the $form object..

for eg if I have

```
class Something
{
   public $somevariable = 'London';

   public function __construct()
   {
     $this->foo();
   }

   public function foo(){
        //Do Something

   }
}

$myObj = new Something();
echo $myObj;
```

The above code gives me an error.
What can I do to echo $myObj and not get an error so I can have something displayed on the screen?

We all know we can do something like,

```
echo $myObj->somevariable;
```

without an error.. How can I do

```
echo $myObj;
```

without getting an error as it is done in the Formidable library.

Comment: `__toString()` ? http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring

Comment: Use `print_r($myObj)` or `var_dump($myObj)`?

Comment: @JayBlanchard it's not quite what _user3620069_ wants?

Comment: @smarber My crystal ball was broken, but I have rebooted and it is coming back online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magic method [`__toString()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring) in your class.  This allows your class to execute the code in that method when your object is treated like a string (i.e. when used with echo).  The method must return a string, otherwise it will raise an error.

You will notice in the library you linked, that they have one in their form class.

```
/**
 * Convert to HTML
 */
public function __toString()
{
    return $this->getHtml();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `__tostring()` magic function to your class

```
class Something
{
  public $somevariable = 'London';

  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->foo();
  }

  public function foo(){
    //Do Something

  }
  public function __tostring(){
    return $this->somevariable;
  }
}
```

Calling `echo $myObj` will print London